# How to select multiple Images from gallery in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I googled and found to choose multiple images on phonegap I need to use the plugin Imagepicker and I've done that.

But while accessing the plugin through my code had no luck, somewhat I did something wrong.

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="openup()">opengallery</button>
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="../imagepicker.js"></script>
 <script>
  function openup() {
     window.imagePicker.getPictures(
        function(results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                alert('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
            }
        }, function (error) {
               alert('Error: ' + error);
           }
      );
  }
</script>
```

The function window.imagePicker.getPictures is global.

And the plugin is also added successfully to config.xml

```
 <plugin name="com.synconset.imagepicker" source="pgb"/>
```

Comment: cordova.js file is included in HTML? Deviceready event listener registered?

Comment: @Gandhi yes it is there but before those file calling i am calling this one

Comment: @Gandhi bro if deviceready file not there means what problem will arise

Comment: @Gandhi and while i am adding platform for those app at the time only cordova.js file is available

Comment: Did you included that cordova,.js file in your HTML?

Comment: @Gandhi bro <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
        </script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="plugins/cordova-plugin-image-picker/www/imagepicker.js"></script>

Comment: deviceready event listener registered? check out this - http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/events/events.html#page-toc-source

Comment: @Gandhi http://paste.ofcode.org/35iHFWPQp4Rrc66NUp8Ci8a

Comment: @bfmags yeah locally i am installed

Comment: @KishoreKumar Invoke plugin code inside deviceready event listener to ensure cordova is loaded fully

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113805/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-gandhi).

Comment: @Gandhi bro can you provide some sample

Comment: Did you fixed this?

Comment: @Gandhi no bro i tried but not get so i left it